# Proper type for OpenSQL IN operand

Tags: abap, opensql

I have function module which imports `my_values`

`my_values` is an custom internal table type of string.

This "my_values" variable contains for example: ["foo", "bar"]

I want to select all values from table `Z_MYTAB` where the column `my_col` is in my_values.

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM Z_MYTAB WHERE 
       my_col in @my_values INTO TABLE @DATA(my_rows).
```

But this fails with an error message:

> table my_values has wrong row structure

(The message was translated to English. The original could be slightly different)

I could loop over `my_values` but I would like to avoid this.

How to do SQL `IN` with host variables which are internal tables?

Comment: I am afraid this is not possible, after IN a range is expected (which is technically also an internal table, just the structure is given (sign, option, low, high)). You have two options: change my_values to a range or instead of IN, use FOR ALL ENTRIES with table my_values

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai thank you for this hint. I used  FOR ALL ENTRIES now, and wrote an answer (see below).

Answer (score 3):

Selection with `IN` is possible only with a [range](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abaptypes_ranges.htm) table.

Conversion of an internal table into a range table can be done like this:

```
DATA ltr_value TYPE RANGE OF string.

ltr_value  = VALUE #( FOR <my_value> IN my_values
                      ( sign   = 'I'
                        option = 'EQ'
                        low    = <my_value> )
                    ).
```

Answer (score 3):

IN openands could be of 2 types:

```
SELECT ... WHERE my_col IN ( value1, value2 , value3)
```

in this case no host expression can be used as right operand

```
SELECT ... WHERE my_col IN sel_tab[]
```

in this case sel_tab is a range like

So you could use the following:

```
DATA sel_tab type range of string.

sel_tab = value #( for ls in my_values ( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' low = ls ) ).
SELECT * FROM Z_MYTAB WHERE
       my_col in @sel_tab[] INTO TABLE @DATA(my_rows).
```

Best regards

Comment: Pay attention that in the first variant, there should be **no space before `value1`** (`IN (value1, ...)`)

Comment: I tried in 7.52 using a [host expression](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenopen_sql_host_expressions.htm), but it's still not a valid syntax (`my_col IN @( VALUE ty_range_my_col( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' ( low = 'value1' ) ( low = 'value2' ) ) )` (still not available in 7.53 according to the documentation)

Comment: Host expressions are not possible in the first variant but host variables are possible: `WHERE my_col IN (@value1,@value2)` (and also non-host classic literals `IN ('foo','bar')`)

Answer (score 2):

User JozsefSzikszai  pointed me to "SELECT FOR ALL ENTRIES".

I found this in the docs:

> For an elementary row type, the pseudo component table_line must be specified for comp.

See: https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenwhere_logexp_itab.htm

```
IF my_values is initial.
  exit.
endif.

SELECT * FROM Z_MYTAB
  FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @my_values WHERE
  column_name = @my_values-table_line
  INTO TABLE @DATA(result_rows).
```